# Angle of aperture in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity

In my lecture notes on relativity, the following is mentioned:
*"Two observers are located at the same position but are both moving to the right at a different speed. When they observe an object located to the right of them, the observer with the lowest speed will perceive the largest opening angle."*

Why is this? To me it would seem that the observer with the highest speed will measure a smaller distance to the object and thus a larger opening angle.

Comment: You are hinting al length contraction I think.  This tells you nothing about what you actually see (where is your eyeball on the spacetime diagram?).  Try this article:  https://www.mathpages.com/rr/s2-05/2-05.htm for an introduction to the concepts; basically you need to consider two space dimensions as well as time. [EDIT: better link]

Comment: [ADDITIONAL] The most relevant stuff starts at "Meanwhile, Einstein's 1905 paper on the electrodynamics of moving bodies . . . "), but read it all anyway!